# Usage of how instead of as?

Tags: word-usage, construction

I am hearing and reading this construction more often:

You can have your meal **how** you want it.

AND

Design your own color combination **how** you like.

Whatever happened to "as"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like a peeve. ***How = however, in whatever manner*** has been normal English for centuries.

Comment: ... It's probably less likely to produce a reaction in the US. But as you say, quite acceptable.

Comment: _How_ can't be used in an embedded _Wh_-question or as a relative pronoun; one must say _the way_ instead. It's the most restricted _Wh_-word, except for _whether_, which can only be used in an embedded yes/no question, and _why_, which can only be used as a relative pronoun when it modifies the word _reason_.

Answer (score 1):

How is proper usage as it implies however.  It seems pedantic, and neither is more correct.